# Referencing column depending on Ids of another column in sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

I am trying to update (reference) a column (oid) of one table with OID of another table's column with certain condition.

Example :

```
Customer Table :
------------------
CID  name   oid
-------------------
1  abc     null
2  abc     null
3  abc     null
4  xyz     null
--------------------

Order Table
--------------
OID  name
--------------
10   abc
11   abc
12   abc
13   xyz
--------------
```

Ouput should be :

```
Customer Table :
------------------
CID  name   oid
-------------------
1    abc     10
2    abc     11
3    abc     12
4    xyz     13
--------------------
```

I have tried the following

```
UPDATE customer as c, order as o
   SET c.oid = o.OID
   WHERE c.name = o.name;
-----------------------------
update customer INNER JOIN order on customer.name=Order.name
SET customer.oid=Order.OID
where customer.oid IS null;
```

But the customer table is being updated as follows

```
Customer Table :
------------------
CID  name   oid
-------------------
1    abc     10
2    abc     10
3    abc     10
4    xyz     13
--------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to assign a row number to each of the entries in `Customer` table and `Order` table.

Thus when making an **`inner join`** between these two tables you have two conditions right now (whereas previously it was one i.e. only name).

One condition is `name` and another one is the `row_number`

You can go with this query:

```
UPDATE Customer CT
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        customerTable.CID,
        orderTable.OID FROM 
        (
            SELECT
                *, 
                @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS row_number
            FROM
                Customer C
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0) var
            ORDER BY CID
        ) AS customerTable
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            *, 
            @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS row_number
        FROM
            `Order` O
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 0) var
        ORDER BY OID
    ) AS orderTable ON customerTable. NAME = orderTable. NAME
    AND customerTable.row_number = orderTable.row_number
) AS combinedTable ON CT.CID = combinedTable.CID
SET CT.oid = combinedTable.OID
```

**Note:** Since joining these two tables on matching `name` is not sufficient for what are you looking for. That's why besides matching name assign a row_number to each of the rows (both in `Customer` and `Order` table. Then make an inner join between these two tables on matching `name` and `row number`. Thus you are restricting one entry to be joined multiple times with other entries from another table.

---

**TEST SCHEMA & DATA:**

<sub>Couldn't add an sql fiddle</sub>

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `CID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `oid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CID`)
);
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES ('1', 'abc', null);
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES ('2', 'abc', null);
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES ('3', 'abc', null);
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES ('4', 'xyz', null);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `order`;
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `OID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES ('10', 'abc');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES ('11', 'abc');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES ('12', 'abc');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES ('13', 'xyz');
```

See now, how does the `Customer` table look like:

```
SELECT
*
FROM Customer;
```

**Output:**

```
CID name  oid
1   abc   10
2   abc   11
3   abc   12
4   xyz   13
```

Comment: Thank You, I will try this out now.

Comment: Please check the query first on the given data that I've posted just now. @Ravikumar

Answer (score 1):

This is very complicated to do.  You need to assign a counter variable to each value -- which is a bit painful in an `update` statement.  But something like this should work:

```
update customer c join
       (select c.*,
               (@rn := if(@n = name, @rn + 1,
                          if(@n := name, 1, 1)
                         )
               ) as rn
        from customer c cross join
             (select @n := '', @rn := 0) params
        order by name, cid
       ) cc
       on c.cid = cc.cid join
       (select o.*,
               (@rno := if(@no = name, @rno + 1,
                           if(@no := name, 1, 1)
                          )
               ) as rn
        from orders o cross join
             (select @no := ', @rno := 0) params
       ) o
       on c.name = o.name and c.rn = o.rn
    set c.oid = o.oid;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try out this but can you please briefly explain what this query is doing? Looks complicated

Comment: @Ravikumar . . . It is enumerating the `name` values in each table, so the enumerated value ("counter") can be used for the join.

Comment: Thank You for the answer but I can select only one answer, so given an upvote.